# (Php) Create a search query with mutiple choices but with MONTHNAME and YEAR

Tags: php, mysql, database, search

So i have a form that has 3 dropdown lists with diferent criterias, one is to search the month (mes), the year (ano) and the type (tipo_id).

what i want to do, and thanks to many questions in here i was able to advance to this place, is that when you select something from the 3 dropdowns, 2 or 1, it shows a table referring the information about it, i can do it, but just for tipo_id, i think the problem is in using  MONTHNAME and YEAR the way am using in my code, i wanted to know how can i make this work, thanks in advance

```
 // Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$mes = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['mes']);
$ano = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ano']);
$tipo = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['tipo_id']);


$meses = array( 
  Janeiro => 'January', 
  Fevereiro =>'February', 
  Março =>'March', 
  Abril =>'April', 
  Maio =>'May', 
  Junho =>'June', 
  Julho => 'July', 
  Agosto =>'August', 
  Setembro =>'September', 
  Outubro =>'October', 
  Novembro =>'November', 
  Dezembro =>'December' 
); 


$sql4 = "SELECT * FROM fluxo ";
$searches = array();
if ($mes  != '') $searches[] = " OR MONTHNAME(data) = '".$meses[$mes]."'";
if ($ano  != '') $searches[] = " OR YEAR(data) = '".$ano."'";
if ($tipo != '') $searches[] = " OR tipo = '".$tipo."'";
if (count($searches) > 0) {
   $sql4 .= " WHERE 1 " . implode(" AND ", $searches);

echo "sql4=$sql4\n";



//$sql4 = "SELECT tipo, movimento, valor, data FROM fluxo WHERE tipo = '".$tipo."' AND MONTHNAME(data) = '".$meses[$mes]."' AND YEAR(data) = '".$ano."' ";
//$result4=mysql_query($sql4); 

$result5 = mysql_query('SELECT SUM(valor) AS value_sum FROM fluxo GROUP BY tipo having count(tipo)>1'); 
$row5 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result5); 
$sum5 = $row5['value_sum'];

$n=1; 

echo "<p>Os seus resultados:<p>";

echo "<table border=0>";
echo "<tr bgcolor='#CCFFCC'>";
echo "<td style='width: 100px;'>Tipo</td>";
echo "<td style='width: 100px;'>Movimento</td>";
echo "<td style='width: 100px;'>Valor</td>";
echo "<td style='width: 100px;'>Data</td>";
echo "</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result4)){ 
    echo "<tr bgcolor='#CCCCCC'>";
    echo "<td style='width: 100px;'>".$row['tipo']."</td>";
    echo "<td style='width: 100px;'>".$row['movimento']."</td>";
    echo "<td style='width: 100px;'>".$row['valor']."</td>";
    echo "<td style='width: 100px;'>".$row['data']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";

}

echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$sql4 = "SELECT * FROM fluxo ";
$searches = array();
if ($mes  != '') $searches[] = " MONTHNAME(data) = '".$meses[$mes]."'";
if ($ano  != '') $searches[] = " YEAR(data) = '".$ano."'";
if ($tipo != '') $searches[] = " tipo = '".$tipo."'";
if (count($searches) > 0) {
   $sql4 .= " WHERE 1 " . implode(" AND ", $searches);
}
```

Comment: it didn´t work, it just shows gets everything that i choose from "tipo_id" ... maybe im missing something

Comment: @Fabiotp91 Are you sure you're processing right MySQL result? Omesh's code would generate a query like `SELECT ... WHERE 1 OR ... AND OR ... AND OR ...` which can't return anything as it's syntacticly incorrect. Another possibility is $_POST['mes'] and $_POST['ano'] are not set or empty.

Comment: ive tried it but it still doesnt works, there must be something else wrong with my code

Answer (score 0):

After imploding `$searches` you end up with a query with up to 3 `WHERE` keywords in it. Removing the first two `WHERE`s should do the trick.

Comment: initially i didn´t had them, but even by that it just brings the results from "tipo_id" without respecting the ones from "ano" and "mes"